# Append <p> and </p> tags to the text in all the cells in a coloumn in vba. The cells in the coloumn keep varying

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to vba.

I have a coloumn with text in each cell. I need to add the html paragraph ( `< p >` and `< /p >` ) tags to each of these cells. The number of rows in this coloumn will vary and hence I need a vba code that can add these tags to all the cells, irrespective of the text in them or the number of cells.

What i tried uptil now requires me to record a macro where i append the tags to each cell manually, and then run this macro.

But this is not useful when there are more rows added to the coloumn.
Please let me know if there is a solution.

The code that i got :

```
Private Sub Test_parah_Click()

Windows("rawdata_test.xlsm").Activate
Range("H2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "<p>Retail prices.</p>"
Range("H3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "<p>Data base platform.</p>"
Range("H4").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "<p>Lisence permits.</p>"
Range("H5").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "<p>Greenberg assessment.</p>"
   End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just use a formula?

```
="<p>"&A1&"</p>"
```

or if you insist on doing it in VBA you can do something like this (skipping over blank cells and using rows.count to make it flexible to various versions of Excel)

```
Sub AddParagraphMarkers()

Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Range("A1:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    If Len(cell) <> 0 Then
        cell.Value = "<p>" & (cell.Value & "</p>")
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Hope that gives you a starting point!

Answer (score 2):

Just select your range and run this code :)

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim aCell As Range

    '~~> Check if what the user selected is a valid range
    If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then
        MsgBox "Select a range first."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For Each aCell In Selection
        If Len(Trim(aCell.Value)) <> 0 Then aCell.Value = "<p>" & aCell.Value & "</p>"
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This will check for the last filled row in the sheet and loop through them,
adding `<p>` and `</p>` to all cells in column "**H**".

```
Sub Test_parah_Click()
    finalRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    For i = 1 To finalRow
        Cells(i, 8) = "<p>" & Cells(i, 8).Value & "</p>"
    Next i
End Sub
```